# Recursively navigating the file system to analyze files in pairs

Tags: python, bash, recursion, filesystems

I have a Python script (let's call it `myscript.py`) I want to apply to a bunch of files that are in a nested directory structure. I will be running the invocations of this script in parallel on a cluster environment, so I want to write a short bash script for this purpose.

So given pairs of files like `xyz_1.gz` and `xyz_2.gz` that are nested in folders like:

```
A > ... > C1 > xyz_1.gz
A > ... > C1 > xyz_2.gz
A > ... > C1 > bunch of other files
A > ... > C2 > xyy_1.gz
A > ... > C2 > xyy_2.gz
A > ... > C2 > bunch of other files
A > ... > C3 > zzz_1.gz
A > ... > C3 > zzz_2.gz
A > ... > C3 > bunch of other files
A > B > some other things
```

It's a silly example above but I hope it conveys the structure at least.

I would like to be able to iterate over the directory structure and call my script:

```
myscript.py xyz_1.gz xyz_2.gz outputfile
```

Such that the output files end up in the corresponding folders.

Most recursive solutions I have seen so far use either `find` or `grep` for each individual file however I need the location as well, to get them in pairs and write to disk at the appropriate place.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** Judging by the answers I got so far, I wanted to clarify that the following three parameters are not known to me in advance:

1. depth of subdirectories holding the .gz files, i.e. I don't know how many intermediate directories exist between
2. names of the subdirectories
3. names of the files, except that they are identical besides the _1/_2 suffix

Answer (score 1):

(Answer to the edited question.)

It is bit harder (less readable) to accomplish in the shell, thus I have resorted to the Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import re
import pprint
from sets import Set
from subprocess import call

group1 = {} # collect here the filenames for _1
group2 = {} # collect here the filenames for _2

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk('.'):
        for filename in filenames:
                ff = os.path.join(root,filename)
                if filename.endswith("_1.txt"):
                        base = re.sub('_1\.txt$','', ff)
                        group1[base] = ff
                if filename.endswith("_2.txt"):
                        base = re.sub('_2\.txt$','', ff)
                        group2[base] = ff

#pprint.pprint(group1)
#pprint.pprint(group2)

# find common ones: the dirs which contain the files with the common prefix:
list1 = Set(group1.keys()).intersection(Set(group2.keys()))

#pprint.pprint(list1)

# call the myscript.py
cwd = os.getcwd()
for base in list1:
        path, filename = os.path.split(base)
        #print path," ",filename
        try:
                os.chdir(path)
                call(['echo', 'myscript.py', filename+"_1.txt", filename+"_2.txt", "outputfile"])
        finally:
                os.chdir(cwd)
```

(Sorry for the crummy Python style: I'm actually a Perl programmer.)

---

> Most recursive solutions I have seen so far use either find or grep for each individual file however I need the location as well, to get them in pairs and write to disk at the appropriate place.

Do not iterate over files - iterate over directories. Example in shell:

```
find -type d -print |
while read DIR; do
    test -r $DIR/xyz_1.gz -a -r $DIR/xyz_2.gz -a -r $DIR/some_other_file || continue
    ( cd $DIR; myscript.py xyz_1.gz xyz_2.gz outputfile )
done
```

Or alternatively, you can still iterate over files, to let `find` check for one of the files for us. Then extract directory from the found file name:

```
find -type f -name xyz_1.gz -print |
while read FN; do
    DIR=`dirname $FN`
    test -r $DIR/xyz_2.gz -a -r $DIR/some_other_file || continue
    ( cd $DIR; myscript.py xyz_1.gz xyz_2.gz outputfile )
done
```

Also, you can move the `cd $DIR` (`os.chdir()` in the beginning; pass directory either as an argument or as env var) into the Python script itself, as well as the check for the input files (silently exit if the files do not exist, for example).

Comment: I like the idea of getting the folders from `find` and iterating over them to see if the files exist. However as I mentioned in my edit to the question, I don't know what the files are called, other than they are of the format xxx_[1/2].gz

Comment: @posdef, I'm ill at home, so my script-fu is bit out of shape at the moment. I'll try to update the answer couple days later. Rough outline: find all `_1.gz` files and prepend to every line dir name + stem of the file name (stem == everything except `_1.gz`); do the same with `_2.gz` files; run the lists through `join` command. (You can do the same in the python with dictionaries: key is the dirname + stem of the file name, value is the file name; find common keys in the two dicts)

Comment: No worries mate, I'll figure it out :)

Comment: @posdef, posted, the Python version of it. Note that I have used the `.txt` for extension and `echo` for the command to be able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bash script performing the following stuff:

```
for i in */*/*.gz
do
    echo "$i"
done | sort | while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    read -r nextline
    $(cd $(dirname "$line") && python3 ~/A/myscript.py "$line" "$nextline" ./outputfile) && echo "Success"
done
```

Script is quite rigid in terms of recursiveness but I've applied it according to your directory structure

Don't know exactly how much files are there but something like can work for you:

```
user@host ~/A$ ls -R
.:
B/  B1/  B2/  myscript.py  script.bash

./B:
C1/

./B/C1:
some_other_file  xyz_1.gz  xyz_2.gz

./B1:
C2/

./B1/C2:
some_other_file  xyy_1.gz  xyy_2.gz

./B2:
C3/

./B2/C3:
some_other_file  zzz_1.gz  zzz_2.
user@host ~/A$ ./script.bash 
Success
Success
Success
user@host ~/A$ cat B/C1/outputfile 
B/C1/xyz_1.gz
B/C1/xyz_2.gz
user@host ~/A$ cat B1/C2/outputfile 
B1/C2/xyy_1.gz
B1/C2/xyy_2.gz
user@host ~/A$ cat B2/C3/outputfile 
B2/C3/zzz_1.gz
B2/C3/zzz_2.gz
user@host ~/A$ 
$
```

I've created dummy python script that writes out the filenames that are given to it as arguments. This is the python script:

```
import sys
#0 is script name itself
input_file1=sys.argv[1]
input_file2=sys.argv[2]
output_file=sys.argv[3]
s=input_file1+"\n"+input_file2+"\n"
with open(output_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however as I don't know the exact depth of hierarchy in advance I cannot rely on two steps of recursion. I have updated the question to clarify